# Search function not working in the below VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, full-text-search, hp-uft, filesystemobject

The below VBScript is to search string in a set of .txt files in a given folder. It works fine for strings like words and so, but when I try to search for dates, like 22-03-2017, it does not show any output. Whats wrong here?

```
Dim filesys
Set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objShell 'instance of the wshSHell object
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
searchStr = InputBox("Please enter the value to search")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Users\abhinkku\Desktop\DoNotDelete\UFT\Scripts"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile In colFiles
    strFile = "C:\Users\abhinkku\Desktop\DoNotDelete\UFT\Scripts\" & objFile.Name
    set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFile)
    If objFile.Size > 0 Then
        If InStr(oFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile).ReadAll, searchStr) = 1 Then
            MsgBox (searchStr & " : string exist ")
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Are you sure that the date exists in the file, in the format you've given?

Comment: sorry its in format 2017-12-28

Comment: Can you show example content of the file being searched?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c):

> ### InStr Function
>
> Returns the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.

`InStr(str1, str2) = 1` checks if the string `str1` *begins* with the string `str2`. If you want to check if the string `str2` is present *anywhere* in the string `str1` you need to check `InStr(str1, str2) > 0`.

Comment: I just used cDate to convert the input string to date and also to convert the search output to Date and used readline instead of readall

Answer (score 0):

Use ">0" instead of "=1"

```
Dim filesys
Set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objShell 'instance of the wshSHell object
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
searchStr = InputBox("Please enter the value to search")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Users\abhinkku\Desktop\DoNotDelete\UFT\Scripts"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile In colFiles
    strFile = "C:\Users\abhinkku\Desktop\DoNotDelete\UFT\Scripts\" & objFile.Name
    set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFile)
    If objFile.Size > 0 Then
        If InStr(oFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile).ReadAll, searchStr) > 0  Then
            MsgBox (searchStr & " : string exist ")
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
```